# Seaborn colormap shows numbers not exist in the data

Tags: python, plot, heatmap, seaborn

I was trying to visualize a dataframe using heatmap from seaborn.
The minimum number in the data is -1.25 as showed below. However, the heatmap encoding ranged from -80 (blue). How can I make the color encoding starts from -1.25 as blue and to 97 as red?

I've tried to use vmax, vmin and robust keywords, but they do not help.

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 20))
                sns.heatmap(hill, annot=annot, linewidths=1, ax=ax, fmt='g', vmin=hill.values.min(), vmax=hill.values.max(), robust=True)
                plt.yticks(rotation=0)



hill.values.min()
Out[30]: -1.25
hill.values.max()
Out[31]: 96.899999999999991
```

[image]

Comment: In your heatmap you use `hill.values.min()` whereas in your subsequent calculations you use `hill.min().min()`. Why?

Comment: @asongtoruin thanks for pointing out. I was trying different ways to get min max. The plot is the same.I updated the post to make it consistent.

Comment: is there any reason why you have `robust=True` when you're setting `vmin` and `vmax`? Maybe try without this

Comment: @asongtoruin tried and did not work :(

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `hill`, which I presume is a dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

First, the functionality you require is the default in seaborn version 0.8 or higher. In this version the code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr1 = np.linspace(-1.25,97,100).reshape(10,10)

sns.heatmap(arr1, cmap="coolwarm") 

plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

An easy option is hence to update your seaborn.

---

In seaborn below version 0.8 you may get the same behaviour by specifying the center of the colormap using the `center` argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

arr1 = np.linspace(-1.25,97,100).reshape(10,10)

center = np.mean([arr1.min(), arr1.max()])
sns.heatmap(arr1, cmap="coolwarm", center=center, vmin=arr1.min(), vmax=arr1.max()) 

plt.show()
```